# measure speed of motor using microcontroller and proximity sensor

Tags: microcontroller

I have to measure the speed of an induction motor sensor here I am using is proximity . now the proximity sensor will give high and low logic to controller. now I am having trouble to understand the logic .I know it's something to do with counters but I am not a able to get the logic or how it will be done. I have to measure the speed and then when the motor reached 90% of rated I have to send a positive logic to a relay driver ic.

kindly explain the logic or how it can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have some sort of timer running in the microcontroller (read the specific chip's datasheet and read code examples on how to do this), and when the proximity sensor goes HIGH, begin the counter. Then the proximity sensor goes HIGH again, record the time, and reset the timer.

The timer you set up in the microcontroller will have some relation to real time, which you can work out, and therefore work out how fast (in rotations per second) the motor spins. The period of time between the two HIGH proximity sensor readings gives you how long it took to spin once. Lets say you convert this to millisecond units, using the clock rate and timer's pre-scale values, and the motor took 45 milliseconds to rotate once. To get rotations per second, simply divide 1000 milliseconds (1 second!) by the time taken to rotate, which was 45 - giving you a speed of 22.2 rotations per second.

In software, you would see this rate being reached, and set the relay output.